# iPod Shuffle 4th generation - red light and not charging

Tags: ipod

My iPod Shuffle 4th generation for a long time it doesn't charge and when I charge it, it only shows 5 second red light. When I plug in and out, it only shows a continuous red light. So what I do next because I put the charger in the wall plug off mobile charger and now it is not charging?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the battery is still able to hold a usable charge, restart your iPod Shuffle. The red light typically means [less than 25% charge](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204428).

> ## [How to force restart your iPod shuffle](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201605)
>
> 1. Unplug your iPod shuffle from its charger and from your computer.
> 2. Use the power switch to turn off your iPod shuffle. If you see green by the switch, your device is on. ([Can't find the power switch?](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201605#switch))
> 3. Wait for ten seconds. Then turn on your iPod shuffle again.

If this does not work, it is likely the internal battery has failed.